# Preventing Subdomain Redirection via SSL Port

Tags: apache, ssl, configuration, virtualhost, lets-encrypt

I have an Ubuntu server with a few subdomains running off virtual hosts (Apache). Most of the virtual hosts are in one file, however one is separated out into two files (since Let's Encrypt doesn't support multiple Virtual Hosts in one .conf file). I have an SSL certificate installed on one of the subdomains only; the other domains I don't currently care about SSL on.

The issue I'm encountering is that HTTPS requests to the other subdomains are routed to the one subdomain, and I don't want that.

So for example, here's my main .conf file structure:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
    <Directory "/var/www/domain">
        ...
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub_domain
    <Directory "/var/www/sub_domain">
        ...
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here's my SSL-installed subdomain .conf file structure:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ssl.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ssl_domain
    <Directory "/var/www/ssl_domain">
        ....
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And finally, here's the .conf file that Let's Encrypt generated to listen for HTTPS requests:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName ssl.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/ssl_domain
        <Directory "/var/www/ssl_domain">
            ....
        </Directory>
        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key.key
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/chain.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Normal HTTP requests to any of the domains work fine. HTTPS requests to the SSL-enabled subdomain work fine. But HTTPS requests to any domain OTHER than 'ssl.domain.com' first generate a 'Your connection is not secure' error, then load from 'ssl.domain.com'. I'd prefer it just generate an error and leave it at that if I'm being honest. How do I prevent this redirection?

I should note that I've tried changing the SSL subdomain's Virtual Host from:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```

to:

```
<VirtualHost ssl.domain.com:443>
```

Which had no effect.

EDIT: I also tried implementing an .htaccess rewrite rule to change https to http. I didn't think it would work, given that a request would hit the virtual host before it ever hit the .htaccess, but thought I'd give it a try. Yeah, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to everyone yelling at their monitors, I did the obvious and just installed SSL across the entire server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define the NameVirtualHost, It will help to handle multiple domains with one ip. 
In the httpd.conf define NameVirtualHost

After that defining the  would do the job. Make sure to restart the apache.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to do the trick. I added `NameVirtualHost *:80` to my httpd.conf but the problem persists (additionally, when I restart Apache it now gives me the warning: `AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release`